# Hiding Keyboard on Background Tap - Gesture Reference Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, keyboard

I have a **board** (UIViewController) which instantiates **card** objects (UIViewControllers). On each card there's a **texfield**. In order to remove the keyboard by clicking on the non card area (= view of the board) I need a reference to the board specified in the **UITapGestureRecognizer**. Here's my current approach.

**Board** (UIViewController) Initializing a card object

```
-(void) addCard:(id)touchEvent{
    CardViewController *card = [[CardViewController alloc]initItemWithText:@"..."];
    [self addChildViewController:card];
    [self.view addSubview:card.view];
}
```

**Card** (UIViewController) On init, add Tap Gesture Recognizer

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
...
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapBackground = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapBackground:)];
    [self.parentViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:tapBackground];
...
}
```

The "background" reference using the parentViewController method doesn't seem to work. Why?

How can I reference from the card back to the board to resign the card's first responder on tap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add the gesture code to Board instead of Card (in viewDidLoad)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapBackground = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapBackground:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapBackground];
```

Comment: Sounds good. However I need to define which textField I want to resign the responder from "[textField resignFirstResponder];" ... and I don't have a direct reference from the board to one single card. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh, I found the solution. Using "[self.view endEditing:TRUE];" instead of the "resignFirstResponder" did work!

Answer (score 1):

1. Place a button on the view
2. Press button and then Editor>Arrange>Send to back
3. And then go and change the type of the button to Round rect to Custom and then make the button cover all of the view.

In ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITextField *textField

}

-(IBAction)bgTouched:(id)sender;

@end
```

In ViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)bgTouched:(id)sender {

[textField resignFirstResponder]

}
```

4 . Connect the textField to the Text Field and bgTouched to the button in the background.